# how to get recent month data in listview in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making an app where I need to fetch recent transactions,

Here I want to load all transaction of current month + other last two months Transactions

here I don't mean to calculate in days...like 60 days + current month days because its making complicated for testing leap year...

What I want is simple,

**Today its 14th Jan 2023 so I want all data of Jan-23,Dec-22,Nov-22**

here is my code for current month + previous month, but not happy with such basic code...need advance level code so that I can update based on Number of months requirement

```
List<TransactionModel> get showRecentTransactions {

    int year=DateTime.now().year;
    int month=DateTime.now().month;

    if(month==1)
      {
        return _transactions.where((element) => element.date.year==DateTime.now().year && element.date.month==DateTime.now().month || element.date.month==12 && element.date.year==year-1).toList();
      }
    else
      {
        return _transactions.where((element) => element.date.year==DateTime.now().year && element.date.month==DateTime.now().month || element.date.month==month-1 && element.date.year==year).toList();
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way:

```
List<String> get showRecentTransactions {
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    late DateTime lastMonth;
    late DateTime secondLastMonth;

    if (now.month == 2) {
      lastMonth = DateTime(now.year, 1, 10);
      secondLastMonth = DateTime(now.year - 1, 12, 10);
    } else if (now.month == 1) {
      lastMonth = DateTime(now.year - 1, 12, 10);
      secondLastMonth = DateTime(now.year - 1, 11, 10);
    } else {
      lastMonth = DateTime(now.year, now.month - 1, 10);
      secondLastMonth = DateTime(now.year, now.month - 2, 10);
    }

    return _transactions
        .where((element) =>
            (element.date.year == now.year &&
                element.date.month == now.month) ||
            (element.date.year == lastMonth.year &&
                element.date.month == lastMonth.month) ||
            (element.date.year == secondLastMonth.year &&
                element.date.month == secondLastMonth.month))
        .toList();
  }
```